# No shared download link from boxItem in BoxFolderPickerViewController

Tags: ios, box-api

How can I get the download_url or shared link from the item returned below? The file id and name, size and date modified are available, but my requirement is to return a download_url or shared link.

```
- (void)folderPickerController:(BoxFolderPickerViewController *)controller didSelectBoxItem:(BoxItem *)item
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

// NSLog("%@",item);
// NSLog(@"%@", item.rawResponseJSON);

 if ([BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.isAuthorized){

      NSLog(@"authorized");


    BoxAPIJSONFailureBlock failure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary){

        [self boxError:error];

    };



    NSDictionary *const queryParametersDictionary = @{@"fields" : @"item_collection"};

    BoxFilesRequestBuilder *builder = [[BoxFilesRequestBuilder alloc] initWithQueryStringParameters:queryParametersDictionary];


  BoxAPIJSONOperation *operation=   [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].filesManager fileInfoWithID:item.modelID

                                         requestBuilder:builder

                                                success:nil

                                                failure:failure];



  }else{NSLog(@"fail");}


}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd need download_url. Do you want to expose it to some other app or user?

If you don't see shared_link in your item rawResponseJSON (debugger: po [file rawResponseJSON][@"shared_link"]), then it is highly likely that file is not shared. You need to share it first.

Here is how you do it, given you already have BoxItem

```
   BoxFileBlock success = ^(BoxFile *file) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.item = file;
            NSDictionary *sharedLinkInfo = [self.item sharedLink];
            // here is your urlString of the sharedLink
            NSString *urlString = [sharedLinkInfo objectForKey:@"url"];

        });
    };


    BoxFilesRequestBuilder *builder = [[BoxFilesRequestBuilder alloc] init];
    builder.sharedLink = [[BoxSharedObjectBuilder alloc] init];
    builder.sharedLink.access = BoxAPISharedObjectAccessOpen;
    builder.sharedLink.canDownload = BoxAPISharedObjectPermissionStateEnabled;
    builder.sharedLink.canPreview = BoxAPISharedObjectPermissionStateEnabled;

    [self.sdk.filesManager editFileWithID:self.item.modelID
                           requestBuilder:builder
                                  success:success
                                  failure:failure];
```

Ideally you also want to provide failure block (omitted here)

Also make sure that you're using latest SDK. It had a small bug fix for sharedObjectFileBuilder that went in yesterday.